# YT.Player Null In Only QA

Tags: jquery, youtube-api

I am trying to create a YT.Player object but is failing. When I console.log() the YT.Player object, I do not see the expected functions associated such as `cuePlaylist()` or `getDuration()`. The code works on my Local and Dev environments, but is failing in my QA environment. Does anyone have any idea why this can be happening?

Through my debugging, I am successful in extracting the Youtube Video ID (which I have console.log), and passing that as a parameter when creating the YT.Player object. I do not understand why YT.Player would report a null video when I am passing it a valid Youutube ID. Furthermore, I am puzzled why it works in my Local/Dev but not QA environments.

```
onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
    createPpdYoutubeObjects();
};

function createPpdYoutubeObjects() {
    var delay = 5000; // need to wait for Youtube videos to load
    setTimeout( function(){        
        // Sets up player tracker, and init the carousel
        var players={};

        $('iframe.ytplayer').each(function() {
            players[ grabYoutubeIdFromUrl($(this).attr('src')) ] = new YT.Player( grabYoutubeIdFromUrl($(this).attr('src')), {
                events: {
                    'onReady': onReady,
                    'onStateChange': onStateChange
                }
            });

            console.log( 'id:   ' + grabYoutubeIdFromUrl($(this).attr('src')) );                
            console.log( players[ grabYoutubeIdFromUrl($(this).attr('src')) ] );                

        });
    }, delay);
};

function grabYoutubeIdFromUrl(path) {
    if (
        typeof path === "string" 
        && path.length > 0 
        && path.indexOf('embed/') > -1 
        && path.indexOf('?wmode', path.indexOf('embed/')) > -1
    )
    {
        var start = path.indexOf('embed/') + 6;
        var end = path.indexOf('?wmode', start);
        return path.substring(start, end);
    }
    return "";
};

<iframe class="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="930" height="524" 
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9VZUcLgtDM4?wmode=opaque&amp;rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;iv_load_policy=3"
    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
<iframe class="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="930" height="524" 
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lF1j8mdmVEI?wmode=opaque&amp;rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;iv_load_policy=3" 
    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

[image: my console]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The YT.Player constructor takes as its first argument either the DOM element or the ID of the HTML element, not just any YouTube ID. You're passing a string that doesn't represent either, and so the results you're seeing is indicative of a YT Player that can't initialize itself because there's no where in the DOM for it to do so.

The solution is to add ID attributes onto your iFrames that are equal to the YouTube src ID, like this:

```
<iframe id="9VZUcLgtDM4" class="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="930" height="524" 
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9VZUcLgtDM4?wmode=opaque&amp;rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;iv_load_policy=3"
    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
<iframe id="lF1j8mdmVEI" class="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="930" height="524" 
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lF1j8mdmVEI?wmode=opaque&amp;rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;iv_load_policy=3" 
    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Why was it working in local/dev? Possible that your iframe code there did have the proper ID attributes and just never properly transferred when you copied your code to a QA environment. But that's much harder to debug. :)

Also, I assume that you only posted a snippet of your code here, correct? Because it won't run as you posted it, given that the onReady and onStateChange functions aren't defined.

Best of luck!