# YT.Player Has Null Value

Tags: youtube-api

I posted a question about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20573498/yt-player-null-in-only-qa) several months ago, and my problem got solved. A few days ago, I got reports that this issue has been occurring again and I am unsure why.

I am trying to create a YT.Player object but is failing. When I console.log() the YT.Player object, I do not see the expected functions associated such as `cuePlaylist()` or `getDuration()`. Through my debugging, I am successful in extracting the Youtube Video ID (which I have console.log), and passing that as a parameter when creating the YT.Player object. I do not understand why YT.Player would report a null video when I am passing it a valid YouTube ID. In addition, I have ensured that my `iframe` has an ID of the YouTube video attached to it.

```
onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
    createPpdYoutubeObjects();
};

function createPpdYoutubeObjects() {
    var delay = 5000; // need to wait for Youtube videos to load
    setTimeout( function(){        
        // Sets up player tracker, and init the carousel
        var players={};

        $('iframe.ytplayer').each(function() {
            players[ grabYoutubeIdFromUrl($(this).attr('src')) ] = new YT.Player( grabYoutubeIdFromUrl($(this).attr('src')), {
                events: {
                    'onReady': onReady,
                    'onStateChange': onStateChange
                }
            });

            console.log( 'id:   ' + grabYoutubeIdFromUrl($(this).attr('src')) );                
            console.log( players[ grabYoutubeIdFromUrl($(this).attr('src')) ] );                

        });
    }, delay);
};

function grabYoutubeIdFromUrl(path) {
    if (
        typeof path === "string" 
        && path.length > 0 
        && path.indexOf('embed/') > -1 
        && path.indexOf('?wmode', path.indexOf('embed/')) > -1
    )
    {
        var start = path.indexOf('embed/') + 6;
        var end = path.indexOf('?wmode', start);
        return path.substring(start, end);
    }
    return "";
};

<iframe id="eEIWYgA2lbQ" class="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="930" height="524" 
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9VZUcLgtDM4?wmode=opaque&amp;rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;iv_load_policy=3"
    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
<iframe id="L7oamJtBpdU" class="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="930" height="524" 
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lF1j8mdmVEI?wmode=opaque&amp;rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;iv_load_policy=3" 
    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

[image: What I see in the YT.Player object]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even with your 5 second delay there's no 100% guarantee that the iframes will be created in the DOM before the code is executed that is trying to read their 'src' attribute, especially given that you haven't noted in your question where it is that you're loading the iFrame library. If you're doing it with a  tag and a src attribute, there's the possibility that recently network conditions have become such that the iframe Library is loaded and the 5 seconds pass before your DOM is fully created. The best way to avoid this is to:

A) Make sure your iframes appear on the page before your scripts that define your functions.

B) Don't load the iFrame library with a  tag and a src attribute, but instead do it like this (just before defining your onYouTubeIframeAPIReady function):

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```

If you're already doing all that and it still isn't working, another thing to try would be to use something like jQuery's $.document.ready() function and load the iframe library in there, just to make absolutely sure that the DOM is complete before trying to extract the src attributes from your iframes.

Hopefully this will steer you in the right direction; if none of these suggestions help, perhaps you could post your full page and scripts and allow us to take a more thorough look?